# Function Pointer (Within Class)

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers, methods

I'm trying to use a function pointer (**fnPtr**) to reference a class method (**fnEmpty**) from within another class method, (in this case the constructor).

The setup program **main.cpp** is

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.hpp"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    Test test;
    return 0;
}
```

and a **test.hpp** that reads

```
#ifndef _test_h
#define _test_h
#include <iostream>

class Test {
    private:

    public:
        void (*ptrEmpty)(void);
        void fnEmpty(){ std::cout << "Got Here" << std::endl;};
        Test(){ ptrEmpty = fnEmpty; };
        ~Test(){};
};

#endif
```

Most of the material on the net details being able to reference a class method **from outside the class** (see [microsoft page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/94579) and [newty.de](http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html#defi)), but not **from inside the class** (as I have done).

Using the above files gives the error

In file included from main.cpp:6:
    ./test.hpp:11:21: error: reference to non-static member function must be called;

So **1) why does this error result?**

If I change **fnPtr** declaration on line 10 to be a **static** so it reads

```
static void fnEmpty(){ std::cout << "Got Here" << std::endl;};
```

This seems to solve the problem. But that begs the question **2) Why does it accept a 'static' if the error says only a 'non-static' is allowed?**

If I remove the static and instead change line 11 (by adding the **&**) so it reads

```
        Test(){ ptrEmpty = &fnEmpty; };
```

I get a whole new error that reads

```
./test.hpp:11:21: error: must explicitly qualify name of member function when taking its address
```

Unfortunately replacing with

```
        Test(){ Test::ptrEmpty = Test::&fnEmpty; };
```

Or variations not including the **Test::** prefix as was done in the links given above do not solve the problem.

I was under the impression that as far as function pointers go, when referencing a function (say **fn**),

```
ptr = fn;
```

is equivalent to

```
ptr = &fn;
```

**3) So why am I getting two different sets of errors when I include and exclude the '&'**

So the ultimate question I have is::

**4) What is the correct way to point to a class method (from within a different method of the same class)? Do I need to include the '*Classname*::' qualifier when Its within the same class?**

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 7):

`fnEmpty` is a non-static member function, which means it takes an implicit first argument, a pointer to the `Test` instance it's being invoked on (the `this` pointer). So the type of a pointer to that member function is

```
void (Test::*ptrEmpty)();
```

Next, to form a pointer to a member function, you need to use the syntax `&ClassName::MemFnName` So, within your constructor

```
ptrEmpty = &Test::fnEmpty;
```

Now your example should compile. You can invoke the function that `ptrEmpty` points to by using

```
Test t;
(t.*(t.ptrEmpty))();
```

When you change `fnEmpty` to be `static` it no longer receives the implicit `this` pointer argument, so it's just like any other pointer to function, and your code compiles.

Comment: @WoodMath It's the name of the class whose member function you want to form a pointer to. So even if `ptrEmpty` were a member of say `class foo`, but you wanted it to point to `Test::fnEmpty`, it'd look the same as above.

Comment: Thanks. With regards to the declaration **void (Test::*ptrEmpty)():**, does the **Test::** prefix refer to the a) class in which the _function pointer_ resides or b) the class in which the _referenced method_ resides? Put another way, If I had another class (say **Foo**) with class method that also accepted and returned a void, would the declaration still read **void (Test::*ptrEmpty)();** since that is where a) the _function pointer_ resides or would it be b) **void (Foo::*ptrEmpty)();** since the _function being referenced_ resides in 'Foo'?

Comment: @WoodMath Maybe an example will help - http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c948e5c13799f1e Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks. 2 more (hopefully quick) questions 1) what happens when you don't know the exact class that the method resides in (you don't know if it is in _Test_ or _Foo_, only that it accepts and returns _void_s. 2) When I remove the **&** from **ptrEmpty = &Test::fnEmpty;** I get a compile error again. Why is the **&** optional when referencing _functions_, but not when referencing _class methods_?

Comment: @WoodMath 1. Use [`std::function<void()>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) 2. A pointer to member function is **not** the same as a pointer to function. With the latter the name of the function will implicitly convert to a function pointer type in most contexts. That implicit conversion rule doesn't apply to member functions, so you must use `&`. Also, looking at your profile, you've never accepted any answers to the questions you've asked, so I'll leave you with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Only accept if you feel it answers the question